# Build and Run current active file in visual studio code for C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, build, ide

I am new to cpp programming, and I am using **Visual Studio Code** as my IDE/editor. I created a custom build task which builds the current active file (file open in editor that I am working on). Below is my `taks.json`.

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++-10 build active file",
            "command": "/usr/local/bin/g++-10",
            "args": [
                //"-g", // include to add debugging support
                "-O2",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                //"${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
                "build/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: /usr/local/bin/g++-10"
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++-10 run active file",
            "command": "${workspaceFolder}/build/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "none",
            "detail": "compiler: /usr/local/bin/g++-10"
        }
    ]
}
```

and the `launch.json`

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++-10 - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "build/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            // "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++-10 build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am able to run the build task to generate cpp object file. But how do I run the file just built from within IDE. I essentially just want to emulate `build and run` for quickly checking programs. I tried creating a new task (the second item in tasks.json's "tasks"), but when run it does not works. I tried finding online but to no avail.

Currently I build the file using this tasks and then switch to `terminal` and run the file. This workflow is ok, but had this been achieved, I would have been able to do `build and run` as supported in common IDEs. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Attaching screen snips for `F5` debugging issue.
[image: Program expecting IO]
[image: Program doing only O]
[image: IO redirection in debug session]
[image: Terminal IO]

Comment: Have you tried pressing the F5 key?

Comment: Yeah, but the key binding is configured for debugging which invokes `launch.json`.

Comment: That is correct.  It should work.  What happens?

Comment: If I write only `cout` messages, they are logged in the debug console. But if it expects input, it does not work.

Comment: You keep writing "it does not work"  That provides no information.  So we can help you, you need to specify what actually happens and how it differs from your expectations.  In this case, it sounds as if it is working correctly but your expectation are wrong.  "It does not work" is not a test report, it is merely whining!

Comment: As far as "expecting input" you likely are talking about standard input.  You need to pipe standard input from a file, something like this:  a < input.txt

Comment: Added snips @ravenspoint

Comment: OK, that's much clearer.  You want to read standard input while in a debugging session.  ( Suggest: change title of your question ).  Have you tried using redirection of standard input?

Comment: Cannot do redirection in debug session. It works normally when I do it from a command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

To read from standard input using a debugging session, standard input must be redirected from a text file.

To redirect standard input, you need a command like this

```
program_name < input.txt
```

So you have to add these commands to you launch

```
"args": [
     "<",
     "input.txt"
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

In launch.json change

```
 "externalConsole": false,
```

to

```
 "externalConsole": true,
```